# Как вызвать класс через скобки из себя?

Tags: python, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

Такая проблема, у нас есть класс, который инициализируется с какими-то данными.
После я хочу вызвать его как функцию, с передачей параметра, числа, как переопределить wr(14) функцию

```
class Work:
    def __init__(self, name, old):
        self.name = name
        self.old = old

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name {self.name}, Old {self.old}"

    # def __new__(cls, name, old=-1):
    #     if old == -1:
    #         return 12
    #     super().__new__(cls)


wr = Work("name", "12")
print(wr)

print(wr(14))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, какое поведение вы ожидаете от такого вызова, но вы можете определить у класса специальный метод `__call__`:

```
class Work:

    ...

    def __call__(self, old):
        self.old = old
        return self

wr = Work("name", "12")
print(wr)

print(wr(14))
```

Тогда ваш код выведет следующее:

```
Name name, Old 12
Name name, Old 14
```

В данном случае я сделал присвоение уже имеющемуся объекту другого значения поля `old`, но можно было там создавать новый объект с таким значением поля и возвращать его. Смотря что вы хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Work:
    def __init__(self, name='', old=0):
        self.name = name
        self.old = old

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name {self.name}, Old {self.old}"

    # def __new__(cls, name, old=-1):
    #     if old == -1:
    #         return 12
    #     super().__new__(cls)


wr = Work(name="Вася", old=12)
print(wr)

wr.old = 14
#print(wr(14))
print(wr)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]